# Best service architecture to listen for requests in queue (queue based load leveling)?

Tags: ios, swift, scalability

I'm working with a system in an iOS app that implements a queue based load leveling architecture to handle multiple incoming notifications coming in from other users (handled/interpreted as requests).  Think of them like invitations, and after putting them in a queue I have a while(true) that checks the queue and handles any objects accordingly:

```
queue.async{
    while true{
        print("#@# checking requests")
        // call some functions to handle any requests
        sleep(3)
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to go about listening to the queue for incoming requests other than a while(true) checking on it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at promises or reactive cocoa. They both have the ability to wait for multiple tasks to complete and then do something

Answer (score 0):

If you used to hear about **Reative Programing** and **Functional Programing** you must take a look at **RxSwift**, it fits your situation perfectly. Briefly, **RxSwift** is Observer design pattern for signal handling.